# Using a paypal payment for authentication of an account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am purchasing some php software that is using paypal as a form of verifying users online accounts. To get verified they make a one-time payment with paypal of $2.00. If successful their account status is changed to verified.

But my concerns are,

This does not tie the users name to the transaction.

Can you get the first_name/last_name and email from the paypal transaction? And can you do this before authorising the payment to be taken? Can I get the user to confirm their name, if the names don’t match the payment doesn’t go through? Or alternatively the payment goes through and then the details are matched.

Either way I would like to have the users name confirmed through this transaction, and email to confirm that the same paypal account isn’t verifying multiple accounts.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Warm Regards,

Comment: what is paying two dollars suppose to 'verify'?

Comment: That they have a valid paypal account, and have been through their authentication process. Ideally though i wan to tie details to this transaction being name and email of account.

Comment: paying you via paypal does not prove any one has a paypal account